# How to improve RPC data throughput over high latency network

Tags: windows, tcp, rpc, wireshark

I am working on client-server software using Microsoft RPC (over TCP) as the communication method. We sometimes transfer files from the client to the server. This works fine in local networks. Unfortunately, when we have a high latency, even a very wide bandwidth does not give a decent transfer speed.

Based on a WireShark log, the RPC layer sends a bunch of fragments, then waits for an ACK from the server before sending more and this causes the latency to dominate the transfer time. I am looking for a way to tell RPC to send more packets before pausing.

The issue seems to be essentially the same as with a too small TCP window, but there might be an RPC specific fragment window at work here, since Wireshark does not show the TCP-level window being full. iPerf connection tests with a small window do give those warnings, and a speed similar to the RPC transfer. With larger windows sizes, the iPerf transfer is three times faster than the RPC, even with a reasonable (40ms) latency.

I did find some mentions of an RPC fragment window at microsoft's site (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg604601.aspx) and in an RPC document (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9629399/chap12.htm search for window_size), but these seem to concern only connectionless (UDP) RPC. Additionally, they mention an RPC "fack" message and I observed only regular TCP level ACK:s in the log.

My conclusion is that either the RPC layer is using a stupidly low TCP window, or it is limiting the number of fragment packages it sends at a time by some internal logic. Either way, I need to make it send more between ACKs. Is there some way to do this?

I could of course just transfer the file over multiple simultaneous connections, but that seems more like a work-around than a solution.

PS. I know RPC is not really designed for file transfer, but this is a legacy application and the RPC pipe deals with authentication and whatnot, so keeping the file transfer there would be best, at least for now.

PPS. I guess that if the answer to this question is a configuration option, this would be better suited for SuperUser, but an API setting would be ideal, which is why I posted this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to control this. This Microsoft documentation page: [Configuring Computers for RPC over HTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains registry settings that set the windows RPC uses, at least when used in conjunction with RPC over HTTP.

The two most relevant settings were:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Rpc\ClientReceiveWindow: DWORD
```

Making this higher (some MB:s, in bytes) on the client machine made the download to the client much faster.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Rpc\InProxyReceiveWindow: DWORD
```

Making this higher on the server machine made the upload faster.

The downside of these options is that they are global. The first one will affect all RPC clients on the client machine and the latter will affect all RPC over HTTP proxying on the server. This may have serious caveats, but a tenfold speed increase is nothing to be scoffed at, either.

Still, setting these on a per-connection basis would be much better.